# Tomcat connection pool with both Shiro and Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, shiro

I'm trying to add some efficiency to my web app with Tomcat jdbc connection pool. Currently i have configured it to work with Shiro - it saves logins in Postgres db. But at the same time i have other part of my app that needs to work with Postgres db. Is it possible to configure only one pool to be available both for Shiro and my app?

Part of the shiro.ini about jdbc:

```
ds = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
ds.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
ds.username = shiroadmin
ds.password = adminshiro
ds.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cleb

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
```

PS: i'm using tomcat pool as a maven dependency

Comment: You should have separate pools for each database.

Comment: @duffymo Can you please explain why? Is it not possible? Or will they interfere in one pool?

Comment: JNDI data sources are one per database.  I erroneously assumed that Shiro was another database vendor.  A Google search told me that Shiro is a security app.  In that case it sounds like it can share the pool with your app.  You should pay attention to the sizing to make sure that you have sufficient connections to accommodate both.

Comment: @duffymo yes, it's security app and it connects to the same db as my app, just another tables.

Comment: You should pay careful attention to the pool size and make sure you do adequate load testing to make sure you've chosen appropriately.